# How can I connect a 24v-powered inductive proximity sensor to a 3D printer control board?

Tags: diodes, voltage-divider, pullup, proximity-sensor

I am attempting to connect an inductive proximity sensor to my 3D printer. The sensor I'm using is a [Zhongde PL-08N2](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32803870919.html) sensor, which is an NPN output NC (Normally Closed) sensor. As I understand it, this sensor has an open collector output, and I am powering it with 24v. When powered up, the sensor's indicator light is normally on, and turns off when metal is placed near the sensor (which I believe indicates normal, correct operation).

The board I am connecting this sensor to is an SKR 1.3 controller board, which operates at 3.3v (though the digital inputs are 5v tolerant) and has a 10K pullup on the board for all the endstop connectors:

[image: SKR 1.3 Endstop Input Schematic]

Of course, I cannot allow the 24v from the sensor to be applied to the input pin, so I used a reverse-biased diode as described at the bottom of [this page](https://mertarauh.com/2017/01/18/dont-trust-the-internet-and-how-to-add-an-inductive-proximity-sensor-to-your-3d-printer-the-proper-and-easiest-way/):

[image: Diode used to protect pin from 12v sensor output]

This did not, however, work for me. The board shows that the sensor is always triggered, whether or not any metal is near the sensor. I believe that may be because the setup in that link is an NPN output NO (Normally Open) sensor, and my sensor is NC.

When I have used this type of sensor before, I used a resistor divider to set the sensor output to an appropriate level, but in that case, there was no hardware pullup on the control board I used. Given that pullup, I do not know how to calculate an appropriate resistor divider for this sensor.

How can I connect this sensor to get the appropriate (3.3v/5v) logic output?

Comment: The easiest way is to use a small relay. Another simple solution is to buy a opto coupler board.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fseASQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The simplest solution.*

Just be careful that no accidental 24 V connection is made to the signal line. If the microcontroller has internal pull-ups R1 can be omitted.

> I think internally to the sensor, the "sense" output will be pulled up to the 24v input when it's not triggered; I believe that would damage the microcontroller?

It would if there is an internal pull-up but you said open-collector. Your link points to a catalog page and there is no datasheet. (This should have been enough to discourage you from a purchase.)

Testing is easy to do:

- Power up the sensor with a high-value resistor - 1 MΩ, say - between the collector and ground and your voltmeter across it.
- Move the target into and out of range. If the voltmeter reading stays close to zero then there is no pull-up. If it increases towards 24 V in either state then there is.

---

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMecTQ.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Using an opto-isolator provides level-shifting and prevents accidental connection of 24 V to the microcontroller. This version uses the opto-isolator in active-high mode. Swap the positions of Q2 and R1 for active-low mode.*

Comment: I think internally to the sensor, the "sense" output will be pulled up to the 24v input when it's not triggered; I believe that would damage the microcontroller?

Comment: See the update.

Comment: With a 1M resistor between the output and ground, when not sensing anything, there is .7v across it, and when sensing something, there is 24v across it. I guess this means it's not open-collector?

Comment: I guess. See the next update.

Comment: And this opto-isolator circuit will work even though there's an onboard (i.e. not software selectable) 10k pullup to 3.3v on the control board?

Comment: Better swap Q2 and R1 then. If you have an internal pull-up you can leave out R1.

Comment: Is R1 here just a current-limiting resistor for Q2?

Comment: No, it prevents the input pin from floating to an undefined logic level. I have shown it as a pulldown. Since you have a pull up you need to eliminate R1 and put Q2 where R1 is.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks!

Comment: Hi, @Mark. If this answer was helped solve the problem can you accept it so the system knows it's solved.